# download file in specific folder in Selenium in macOSX

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download any file (jar file) from web in Specific folder in Mac System using selenium but every time downloading in downloads folder

Chrome Version -76
Chromdriver 76
OS -Mac

I tried with given code but still not able to save the file in a specific folder

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();

HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory","/Users/username/Documents/WORKSPACE/ARU1/");

Options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Every time it downloads in the download folder

Answer (score 0):

You must add `setDownloadBehavior`.

For example:

```
HashMap chromePrefs = new HashMap();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory","/Users/username/Documents/WORKSPACE/ARU1/");
chromePrefs.put("browser.set_download_behavior","{ behavior: 'allow' , downloadPath: '"+_PATH_TO_DOWNLOAD_DIR+"'}");
```

Comment: i resolved by changing the selenium version to new latest version, but still did not get the logic why was it happening with 3.14 version in mac system,  Thanks Murta for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using the browser for downloading content, leave it to Chrome developers/testers.

I believe you should rather get [href attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) of the element you want to download and obtain it using [OkHTTP library](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

If your site requires authentication you could fetch [cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) from the browser instance and pass them to [OkHttp Request.Builder](https://gist.github.com/tsuharesu/cbfd8f02d46498b01f1b)

Comment: i am using for downloading purpose , like you clicked in a button and tha file is getting downloaded in your download folder, so i want to download the file in specific folder , for that i was trying  this...Thanks for help Dmitri